# How to merge 2 list menus in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Does anyone know the way or plugin needed to combine/merge 2 list menus into 1 menu list in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Combines the markup of two menu areas into one. I have not tried it but hopefully it will work for you.

> Get the markup list items in the first menu.

```
$menu = wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'=> 'menu-1',
    'fallback_cb'   => false,
    'container'     => '',
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
    'echo' => false
) );
```

> Display menu-2 with all the list items from menu-1 included.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu-2',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s ' . $menu . '</ul>',
) );
```

[Reference link](https://gist.github.com/devinsays/bcee062eb97712698a96)

Comment: Thanks for respondes @Gufran Hasan, but where is can i put this code?